# Qt on windows with mingw and no MSVC redistributable?

Tags: windows, qt, dependencies, mingw

Qt supports compiling all including qml without MSVC. So how to install qt creator and qt studio without them, how to create qt package that will not rely on MSVC at all?

Comment: Such distribution is needed for example when we have no admin rights in a classroom...

Answer (score 0):

You could build QtCreator with mingw and distribute it in your classroom : take a look at the Readme https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot install MSVC redistributable run times, you can either build your own package using MinGW (see other answers, but note that you only need to rebuild Qt Creator and Qt 3D Studio, not Qt intself).

Or you can install the official packages that do depends on MSVC runtimes (for QtCreator and Qt Studio) and instead of installing the MSVC Redistributable Package, you can copy paste the required DLLs to the installation folder (e.g `C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin` for Qt Creator).

For Qt Creator it seems that you will need:

- `MSVCP140.DLL`
- `VCRUNTIME140.DLL`

You can check the missing DLLs using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) or similar tools.

*Note that if copying the DLLs around is not recommended by Microsoft, but it does work. And it is less cumbersome that rebuilding Qt Creator.*

> It's also possible to directly install redistributable Visual C++ DLLs
>   in the application local folder, which is the folder that contains
>   your executable application file. For servicing reasons, we do not
>   recommend that you use this installation location.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/redistributing-visual-cpp-files